# What happens when we move files/folders to trash as root user?

Tags: nautilus, root, delete, trash, 20.10

So, earlier this day, I've mistakenly moved to trash a file of around 80M as a root user from nautilus. And then after realizing about what a mistake I made I had no choice left but to ask here at askubuntu, well because I knew for some reason Trash is not kinda implemented for root user(as I am unable to access trash:/// as superuser) and I can't even go on to trash and remove(or restore) as a normal user(I tried but didn't help). So, now I wonder what actually happens to those unfortunate files if I do so. I mean are they in fact moved to some trash but I can't go there and do the last thing or whether they are actually permanently deleted but for some reason developers forget to manage this special case and renaming `Move to Trash` with `Delete Permanently`. Well I think I've experienced one of the dangerous thing about running GUI applications with sudo. But anyway.

I once thought about raising an issue but I deemed to ask here at first as right. And now let me tell you what else did I try to understand this situation better; I tried to delete a file with `Shift+Delete` and then as expected a dialog did come up and asked me whether I really wanted to delete the file or not.

So I want to know what actually happens to those and if i should raise an issue about it?

I use Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: Run `sund find /root/.local/share/Trash/files`. Are your files listed there? If possible, please add the output into your question.

Comment: @Boba Yes the file is there. is it safe to delete then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are moved to the folder `/root/.local/share/Trash/files` you can remove it from there. But don't forget to remove the *trashinfo* too. These are stored in `/root/.local/share/Trash/info`.